# Why are some of my created vectors working and others are not for the same method of making sub datasets?

Tags: r, vector

I'm working with a dataset that contains multiple species. To make visualizing the data easier, I have made vectors to divide the data by species.

Here is my data:
[list of species with sex, weight, and forewing length data - it is part of my datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqNZw.png)

| species | sex | weight | forewing length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chlosyne janis | female | 0.0555 | 3.319 |
| chlosyne janis | male | 0.0272 | 3.114 |
| chlosyne janis | male | 0.0364 | 2.756 |
| chlosyne janis | male | 0.0278 | 2.678 |
| chlosyne erodyle | female | 0.0593 | 3.157 |
| chlosyne lacinia crocale | male | 0.0364 | 2.756 |
| chlosyne lacinia crocale | female | 0.0143 | 2.688 |
| chlosyne lacinia crocale | male | 0.0085 | 2.537 |
| chlosyne lacinia crocale | male | 0.011 | 2.25 |
| chlosyne lacinia lacinia | male | 0.0164 | 2.801 |
| chlosyne hippochrome | male | 0.0301 | 1.963 |
| chlosyne acastus neumoegenio | male | 0.0121 | 1.55 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0225 | 1.809 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0139 | 1.491 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0179 | 1.869 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0186 | 1.806 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0232 | 2.125 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | female | 0.0143 | 1.682 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.017 | 1.763 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0157 | 1.593 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0142 | 1.393 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0152 | 1.463 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0105 | 1.515 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0079 | 1.485 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0185 | 1.592 |
| anthanassa texana seminole | male | 0.0143 | 1.505 |
| anthanassa texana texana | female | 0.0225 | 1.767 |
| anthanassa texana texana | female | 0.0261 | 1.869 |
| anthanassa texana texana | male | 0.0206 | 1.759 |

This is a section of the code I've been running:

```
chlosyne.janis <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne janis",] 
head(chlosyne.janis) 

chlosyne.erodyle <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne erodyle",] 
head(chlosyne.erodyle) 

c.lacinia.crocale <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne lacinia crocale",] 
head(c.lacinia.crocale) 

c.lacinia.lacinia <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne lacinia lacinia",] 
head(c.lacinia.lacinia) 

chlosyne.hippochrome <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne hippochrome",] 
head(chlosyne.hippochrome) 

c.acastus.neumoegenio <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne acastus neumoegenio",] 
head(c.acastus.neumoegenio) 

a.texana.seminole <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "anthanassa texana seminole",] 
head(a.texana.seminole) 

a.texana.texana <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "anthanassa texana texana",] 
head(a.texana.texana)
```

For some of the vectors, I can see the number of observations with the associated variables, and for others it will give me 0 observations with the associated variables.

I have double check spelling in the dataset and in the code. c.lacinia.lacinia and c.lacinia.crocale consistently come up with 0 observations, even after reloading the dataset.

Is there a better way to make a vector that retains the observations?

Comment: Please provide the data as a dataframe using `dput()'

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(tribe.df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(tribe.df, 20))`.

Comment: If it is really a data.table you should do
tribe.df[species == "anthanassa texana texana",]

Comment: I have added the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `data.table` replace `chlosyne.janis <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "chlosyne janis",]` 
with `chlosyne.janis <- tribe.df[species == "chlosyne janis",]`